# Invalid ImageList Index error [Delphi]

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe8

This window appear all the time when I change Delphi's tab 'Code' to 'Design'. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Still happens in Delphi 10.2.3

Comment: Still happens in Delphi 10.3.2

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this exact issue before using Delphi XE8. I found no solution other than restarting the IDE when it happens.

In particular, this happened whenever I would switch between Local Desktop and Remote Desktop. For example, I would start the IDE from locally at the computer itself. Then, I would go to another computer, and open Windows Remote Desktop to that computer, into the same desktop session, and when I went to use the IDE, it would give me the same `Invalid ImageList Index` error repeatedly.

Since then, I've been using Delphi 10 Seattle, as well as not using Remote Desktop. So I can't say whether this has been fixed yet in later Delphi versions. But if I recall, past attempts to use Delphi 10 Seattle via Remote Desktop have been successful.

Answer (score 2):

i think i found the problem.
if look carefully on the error details.
the firs row show calling delete on custom image list...
so i find out if i delete FMX.ListBox from uses, it will solve my problem.
and it worked. so i think the problem is a bug on Firemonkey ListBox unit.

Comment: Worked! But I need FMX.ListBox... T.T

Answer (score 1):

I Solved with a simple Alt+F12